# How do Trade Winds work?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I can't find any real information on them; how do they influence colonial and trade range in only one direction, and by how much?

Comment: I thought they only affect trade value, but I may be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have confirmation, but I am guessing the one-directional system is done traveling from your capital outwards, so Europe can colonize America with a lower colonial range than America colonizing Europe because the one directional boost. Which trade nodes you can send merchants to is probably affected similarly.

I can't find information about the quantity of distance it increases.